# Correct way of naming final static variables if condition

Tags: java, variables

What is the cleanest way to name a variable depending on a condition?

```
 private static final String STRING = (Utility.OLD ? "FOO_OLD" : "FOO_NEW");

 private static final String STRING_OLD = "FOO_OLD";
 private static final String STRING_NEW = "FOO_NEW";
```

Answer (score 1):

Constants are used for values that are not intended to change in the first place. Don't assign them until you know what the value is going to be.